# Magento 2.4.2, Magento 2.4.1-p1 and Magento 2.3.6-p1 all available on 9 February 2021. Which to choose?

Tags: upgrade, magento-upgrade

We tried upgrading to Magento 2.4.1 but are having many issues so we are going to postpone the upgrade.

*The full and final versions of Magento 2.4.2, Magento 2.4.1-p1 and Magento 2.3.6-p1 will be available to the general public on 9 February 2021.*

**Which of these would you recommend and why?**

Answer (score 1):

If I was developing a brand new Magento 2 store, or migrating Magento 1 to Magento 2 now, then I would start developing with the most up to date public release of Magento 2 available which as of January 2021 is Magento 2.4.1.

I would then plan to upgrade to the latest release or patch, i.e. 2.4.2 before I went live with my production store.

If I already have a live production store running an older Magento 2 release then I would evaluate new releases or patches and according to my business requirements and risk assessments plan to upgrade where appropriate. I would certainly plan to move to the latest release before my current release i.e. 2.3.x went End of Life.

In your case - if you are having migration issues with Magento 2.4.1 then you will have the same (and quite possibly more) issues with Magento 2.4.2 in February.